# How can I run nunit test with parameterized Repeat attribute

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

How can I tell NUnit to repeat tests in a fixture "n" times, when "n" is a variable in the test class that is set using TestFixtureSource instantiation of the base test class?

Actually I want to run my test suite two times:

- Once each test should not repeat i.e. [Repeat(1)]
- In another run, all of them must be repeated by the amount that I say! (You should know that, this time I do something in the constructor, and then I want to run same tests multiple times)

I don't want to copy the test suite two times!!
I want NUnit to run it automatically!!!

Comment: why do you need that at all? That may effect how the actual solution to that problem looks like, chances are running them multiple times won't have any effect.

Comment: you may simply make your `TestCaseSource`-method return the same testcases multiple times. But again: why do you need that? That seems pretty odd to me.

Comment: Why is it odd? I do not want to repeat test cases in a suite constant times! I want to be able to set the number of repetition in the constructor! Why do you think this requirement is odd! Seems pretty logical to me!

Comment: because it implies that the results of the first execution may be different from the second one for instance, making your tests pretty un-deterministic.

Comment: No, it does not imply that. It simply gives me the tools needed for repeating test cases different number of times, regarding tester's request! Maybe a tester wants to change the state of the system (for example put light load on PC) and then run test suite just once, or maybe the tester wants to put the system in another state (for example put heavy load on PC) and run the suite multiple times. The test suite is always the same! Just state of the PC is changing!!!

Comment: exactly that's the problem... when you change the state of your system, the test is completely undeterministic and highly depends on the systems current state. In fact you have a hidden dependency. So you actually have different tests. Instead of tweaking an an existing framework to your needs, you should consider to rethink your test-architecture.

Comment: Changing the state of the system on which code is running is not the same as changing the state of the code itself. They are two different things.

Comment: From my perspective there's no difference between a system-dependency (e.g. state of your network) and a code-dependency (e.g. some other class). In both caseas there's a dependency to your actual class. You can either fake that dependency (usually within a unit-test using a mocking-framework), or you use your actual environment (for example a an external database which would result in some integrational test). Either way the dependency *is* part of your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems you want to test for external dependencies - e.g. the network-state, an external database or whatever. So in fact you have an integration-test.

How you setup the dependencies for your tests is completely up to you, however I'd argue to do as much as possible within your code so your tests stay deterministic. What's the point of a green test, when you need to examine the exact result based on some other system - e.g. reading your log-files if *really* everything went well? Furthermore having everything in a single code-base enables for version-control and you easily see every change to your tests as well as to your entire system.

As test-code is also just code, you can of course refactor it in order to reduce code-duplications for similar environments. So you may have two test-methods with nearly identical code, that only differ in a database-connection for instance. You don't need to run the first test, change your systems state, run the second test Instead you can embed the entire state-change directly in your code. See this short example:

```
[Test]
public void Test1() 
{
    // code for setting up your systems new state
    var target = new MyClass();
    target.DoSomething();
    Assert.Pass();
}


[Test]
public void Test2() 
{
    // code for setting up your systems new state
    var target = new MyClass();
    target.DoSomething();
    Assert.Pass();
}
```

You can now refactor that so your two tests do the exact same things:

```
[Test]
public void Test2() 
{
    // code for setting up your systems new state
    Test();
}

[Test]
public void Test2() 
{
    // code for setting up your systems new state
    Test();
}

private void Test() 
{
    var target = new MyClass();
    target.DoSomething();
    Assert.Pass();
}
```

An alternative that enables you to run the exact same test again and again is by simply provide a dynamic number of testcases via the `TestcaseSource`-attribute:

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTestCases))]
public void Test() 
{
    // code for setting up your systems new state
    Test();
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetTestCases() => Enumerable.Repeat(new TestCaseData(), numberOfRepitions);
```

However that will run the tests one after the other, so you won't have time to change your systems state between two tests.

Comment: You are right. I really need this feature in NUnit so that I'll be able to repeat test cases in a fixture dynamic number of times. Using Repeat attribute in NUnit, I can only set a constant number of repetition. But I want to instantiate THE SAME test fixture and tell NUnit runner to repeat this instance 'x' times and repeat that instance 'y' times. I think NUnit does not support this feature. Maybe because it is absurd or maybe because it is not yet possible.

Comment: @siiifsxa I added a second solution, that enables you to dynamically set the number of repetitions.